"Could not build wheels for scikit-learn, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects",
I am installing niwidgets , during the installation it throws wheel compilation error:
** Building wheel for scikit-learn (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [820 lines of output]
      /private/var/folders/t_/tkgl1f8j7y14c3d40pcymqmw0000gn/T/pip-install-oqhx_cr5/scikit-learn_1cef91db2c464800815e767404a4ca2f/setup.py:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
        from pkg_resources import parse_version
      Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
      /private/var/folders/t_/tkgl1f8j7y14c3d40pcymqmw0000gn/T/pip-install-oqhx_cr5/scikit-learn_1cef91db2c464800815e767404a4ca2f/setup.py:242: DeprecationWarning:

      
        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.}

Note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
Running setup.py clean for scikit-learn
Failed to build scikit-learn
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Full log: https://paste-bin.xyz/8121468

Try pip install --only-binary :all: scikit-learn, and please format your error by editing your question.

already tried, and The Requirement was satisfied. still getting the same error

Part of your error message states:

numpy.distutils is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result of the deprecation of distutils itself. It will be removed for Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present. It is recommended to use setuptools < 60.0 for those Python versions.}

You appear to be using Python 3.11 as seen in your complete error log, this means that you have to use setuptools < 60.0 as recommended in your error message.
You can get setuptools 59.8.0 by running pip install setuptools==59.8.0 in your environment.

I have tried it but still same error showing
